# Is there value in discovering new functions? How?

Tags: functions, soft-question, mathematical-modeling

Today I was thinking of discovering new functions. Many functions come from physics for example, where they are made to "model" some behavior.

But surely there are other sources for functions than physical things.

But how can one "gauge", whether such functions are useful or not? And for what they could be utilized?

Comment: Well, another source might be  "tractable" functions...functions about which it is easy to prove results.  These might arise from differential (or integral) equations or from conveniently expressed infinite sums (or products).

Comment: What kind of functions are you looking for?  Using the modeling tags suggests you may be interested in ones that solve differential or partial differential equations.  That universe is quite different from the combinatoric ones, for example.

Comment: @RossMillikan I'm merely interested in the possibility of discovering new functions and then discovering that they can be applied to something. Sort of like discovering a "hidden" structure and then noticing that it exists elsewhere. But rather than going purely mathematical route, I could try to discover functions by analysing "functional" things. For example the trigonometric functions have quite many ways to view them. They show up in different sorts of contexts. One could discover them not merely by looking at triangles, but also e.g. vibration or periodic movement.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that people don't usually invent new functions and see what they are good for, they try to solve problems that lead them to define a function.  They write up the solution and others notice that the function helps with their problem, too.  If a function shows up enough, we give it a name so we can talk about it.  That may prompt others to work on the properties of the function.  As you say, the trig functions show up lots of places.  Once they show up so much we put a lot of work into understanding them.

One example would be solving the $14-15$ puzzle.  Working on this naturally leads to the idea of even and odd permutations.  If that idea wasn't already known you would define that function and use it in your solution.  There are lots of other combinatoric problems that the parity of a permutation solves, so it would rapidly become popular.

Comment: I however have this philosophical idea of the needed patterns being inscribed to natural things that can be discovered when they are analyzed or measured. So my idea is to discover new functions by looking at something empirical, rather than through abstract problems.